# Getting value with a Lens s t a b

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I would like write a function which turns a function (a -> b) into a function (s -> t) with the help of a Lens s t a b **(edit: I realised that this function already exists with `Setter s t a b` and is called `over` or `%~`, but it doesn't answer the question below of using a Lens to get a value)**. It seems simple, but I'm getting a confusing type error. To make an even more minimal example, consider the following function which simply returns the value extracted from the second argument by the lens:

```
f :: Lens s t a b -> s -> a
f l s = s ^. l
```

This doesn't compile. There are 2 errors, both in the second argument of ^. (namely l):

- Couldn't match type 't' with 's'
- Couldn't match type 'a' with 'b'

However, the following compiles:

```
f :: Getter s a -> s -> a
f l s = s ^. l
```

Then, I realised that in the [hierarchy of lens types](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.8/lens-4.12.3/index.html), the arrow between Lens and Getter specifies s=t, a=b. Is there no way to use a general `Lens s t a b` to get a value of type `a` from a value of type `s`?

Comment: Why don't you just take `Lens s s a a` or simply `Simple Lens s a`?

Comment: Because I need to change the types of both the container and the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with using `^.` isn't [its implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/src/Control-Lens-Getter.html#%5E.), but its type signature. If we lift its definition, we can use it for `f`:

```
f :: Lens s t a b -> s -> a 
f l s = getConst $ l Const s
```

This is most easily understood if you expand the definition of `Lens` : `forall (f :: * -> *). Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way.

```
f :: Lens s t a b -> s -> a
f l s = getConst (l Const s)
```

This is also exactly the definition of `(^.)`. I'm not sure why the type of `(^.)` is restricted in this way, possibly just for simplicity.

Comment: I suspect the more generic signature makes type inference harder and thus necessitates some ugly signatures that `^.` doesn't require.